# Passing an attribute from method to another method python

Tags: python, django, oop, methods

Excuse me, I am pretty new to oop in python, but I'm wondering how to pass the value of `tld_object` in `gather_site()` to the method `gather_path()`

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Class Initialized"

    def gather_site(self):
        tld_object = Tld.objects.filter(id=3)
        return tld_object

    def gather_path(self):
        path_object = PathsOfDomain.objects.filter(FKtoTld=)
```

**models.py**

```
class Tld(models.Model):
    ##default table PK here.
    ##fields here

class PathsOfDomain(models.Model):
    ##default table PK here.
    ##fields here
    FKtoTld = models.ForeignKey(Tld)
```

Basically is what is happening in table `Tld`, has a 1:M relationship to `PathsOfDomain` and I want to be able to get the related paths, based on `tld_object` which comes from database in `gather_site()` method

Any help is graciously appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The line `return tld_object` should be indented. Not sure if that's just a formatting error in your post, or if your code is actually like that.

Comment: are you using some ORM here? ...

Comment: This class is housed within django (latest)

Comment: you would need to show us your model classes probably ... at least minimal model classes that include the relationship definition

Comment: Added minimal version

Comment: If you do `self.tld_object = Tld.objects.filter(id=3)`, you can access `self.tld_object` from every methods in that object. E.g. `PathsOfDomain.objects.filter(FKtoTld=self.tld_object.pk)`. *But* you should be using `get` instead of `filter` if you want only one object.

Comment: Thanks for that. Care to put that as an answer? I am only using id=3 for testing purposes now, it will definitely have more than 1 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def gather_path(self):
    path_object = PathsOfDomain.objects.filter(FKtoTld=3)
```

I think should work fine ...

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Class Initialized"

    def gather_site(self, id):
        # Note I'm using get instead of filter when dealing with PKs.
        # Only one object is going to be returned.
        self.tld_object = Tld.objects.get(id=id)
        return self.tld_object

    def gather_path(self):
        # At this point you have to have self.tld_object already set,
        # Either check it exists or give it a default value.
        path_object = PathsOfDomain.objects.filter(FKtoTld=self.tld_object.id)
```